I want to add the automatically Dropdown Box based on the First value
. In this form I want to add the google apps script for automatically select the Question -2 Value (Item Name) based on Question-1 Value (SKU Code).
. This is the image of sheet from I want the value in the google form.
I tried many thing but not get the desirable results. I tried i.e., Formulas, Functions, Codes etc to change the values but not getting which i want.

This is not possible with Google Forms as it never interacts with the server to "check" answers throughout the completion of the form.  You may have to build and deploy a custom web app using Apps Script or try the "Dynamic Fields" add on in Google Forms.
